# GNU C++ can not create vector of constant custom class instances

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, vector

I have a very simple demo program that compiles well on Microsoft Visual C++:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class String
    :public wstring
{
public:
    String(void)
    {
    }

    String(const String &other)
        : wstring(other)
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<const String> v;
    v.push_back(String());
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

It creates vector of constant strings. However, in GNU C++ 4.8.2 it gives a lot of errors that try to say that it is impossible to create vector of constant String objects. When I replace `vector<const String>` with `vector<String>`, it compiles.
What is the reason of such GNU C++ behavior?

Comment: For certain operations,  type must be assignable (and/or move variant). `const T` does not satisfy that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library containers make use of allocators. For an allocator-aware container type `X` and its allocator `A`, `X::value_type` and `A::value_type` must be the same. Since your `X::value_type` is `const String`, `A::value_type` will also be `const String`. However, the standard only defines allocators with `value_type`s that it are "any non-const, non-reference object type" (Table 27 [allocator.requirements]) The requirements for an allocator with a `const` type are not defined, so just attempting to create a container with a `const` value type will result in undefined behaviour.

In addition to this, many operations on containers require the value type to be copy/move assignable, so you probably wouldn't get very far with using it.

Comment: undefined behaviour? the OP said it's compile time error.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's perfectly valid for code with undefined behaviour to give an error.

Comment: Thanks, you must be right; the fact that GNU can not compile the code and MSVC compiles it shows that it is really "undefined" behavior, so Microsoft decided to allow it to compile and GNU to not allow.

Comment: @VASoftOnline: That's very strange, I can't imagine what Microsoft did that would cause it to compile.

Comment: @Mooing Duck I don't know for sure, but I am primarily Windows programmer, and I some times port apps from Windows to Linux; Visual C++ I think fixes some errors during compilation, because I have a lot of examples when software compiles with VC++ and works for months without problems, and GCC can not compile it. I think when I write `vector<const String>` in VC++ it may silently ignore `const` and compile it like `vector<String>`, so programmer may even don't know that it is problem like in my example.

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` deals with instances of your class in a specific way in regards to memory management. Some of operations it performs on data require copy constructor and assignment operator or a noexcept move constructor/assignment operator. GCC is quite correct not to compile your example which doesn't have any of these. `const T` cannot be a valid type for a `std::vector`.